# How to return success on a Post API call to MongoDB in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I'm new to fetching and posting data using an API, and I can't work out how to do something once my Post has been completed.

I have a function that calls the API with the Post data. I need to set the loading state to false once the Post has been completed. Everything works apart from that, the data gets sent to Mongo, I just need to turn off my loading spinner once it has completed.

How do I do this, please?

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
const postData = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    await axios.post('/api/addData',form)
    .then(response => {
        setLoading(false)
    })
}
```

And this is the API bit:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from "util/mongodb"
export default async (req, res) => {
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase()
    await db
        .collection("posts")
        .insertOne(req.body);
}
```

Comment: res.sendStatus(200); after your await db.collection. And replace .then by .finally so even if you have an error your loading will still stop

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Nicolas, this works. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two potential problem in your code, first you're not sending any data back to the front in your backend code. Usually you send back the id of the inserted element (It can be usefull to do some mutation in your front), you'll also need to try catch your call to the db to notify that something went wrong to the front end side :

```js
import { connectToDatabase } from "util/mongodb"

export default async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { db } = await connectToDatabase()
      const insertedPost = await db
        .collection("posts")
        .insertOne(req.body);

      res.status(201).send(insertedPost.insertedId);
      // again it's up to you to know what can be usefull to your front-end to use
      // Look at http status code online to know what's the best fit
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message);
     // send whatever that can be usefull for your front end to handle the error
    }
}
```

In your front-end code you're using await with .then, it's weird usage. You can put your setLoading(false) after the await without the .then but you'll still need to try catch it. What I prefer to do is using the finally block to stop loading, so if my api call fail the loading is still stopped :

```js
const postData = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/api/addData',form)
      // do something with response
    } catch (err) {
      // notify user that something went wrong
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
}

const postData = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    axios.post('/api/addData',form)
    .then(response => {
        // do something with response
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // notify user that something went wrong
    })
    .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
    })
}
```